# How to detect blank lines from istream in c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11

How to detect blank lines from istream in c++11?

Is there a simple method, or I will have to do something like
remove empty spaces and tabs and then see if the resulting string
is empty?

Comment: "Detect" and then what? You could be clearer about your requirements.

Comment: Awesome. Well, stick it in a requirements document and we'll go from there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::string s;
if (!std::getline(in, s)) {
    // There wasn't another line.
}
auto pred = [](unsigned char const c) { return std::isblank(c); };
if (std::all_of(s.begin(), s.end(), pred)) {
    // This line was empty.
}
```

Comment: @Nawaz why not? Oh, I guess he wants lines with just spaces to count.

Comment: Yes I also want to detect such empty lines, that contain only empty spaces and tabs...

Comment: I liked the previous version better! Why did you separate it into separate predicate outside? :(

Comment: @user3111311 because the argument you pass to `std::isblank` has to be in the range `0..UCHAR_MAX`, but `char` can be signed, so you need the `unsigned char` conversion to prevent cases of undefined behaviour.